# Identify Valve Noise RECORDING

Tags: noise, valve

What's that sound?
 Sorry a little long (15:00) see notes below for TLDR.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4e9w0OOuGinSVhqMVM5OHQwZ3c/view?usp=sharing

Note good power and smooth shifting at 3m10s through 3m24s.

Note persistant 'dieseling' sound, top-end chatter.

Always at 1600-1900 RPM, not at idle, not at 2000 RPM and above.

Note good power under heavy load probably 15% grade at 2000 RPM at 8m20s through 8m50s.

Note nice quiet idle, you can hear the injectors.

2000 accord lx stock 110,000 miles

Comment: Sadly I have no device here that can play that file. Any way to pop it up as a wav or mp3?

Comment: Or, recording it as a video and post to YouTube seems to work well for many folks.